# Vectorizing these loops in R

Tags: r, vectorization

I'm working on porting some C code to an R package and have a series of nested loops that run very slowly. In the example below the arrays are quite small but in the application I need they are an order of magnitude larger. This is a case where (at least partially) vectorizing the loops should be possible but I've been working on this long enough I'm frazzled and can't figure out what to do. The work the loops do themselves is trivial (!) just getting the cumulative sum of dot products. But for whatever reason I'm stuck.

```
# Input
n <- 100
m <- 5
x <- matrix(rnorm(n*m),ncol=m)
# make some random starts and stops for the data
x[1:20,1] <- NA
x[1:50,2] <- NA
x[61:80,3] <- NA
x[91:100,4] <- NA

# We will lag the data from 
# 0:biggestLag sequentially
biggestLag <- 3

# Output structure
dotProductSums <- numeric(biggestLag+1)

# Do three loops -- what can be vectorized here?
# Start with unlagged case and then lag by one to biggestLag
for(k in 0:biggestLag){
  # do column j
  for(j in 1:m){
    # do column i
    for(i in 1:m){
      # Require at least two data points to 
      # overlap, otherwise break
      mask <- which(rowSums(!is.na(x[,c(j,i)]))==2)
      if(length(mask)==0) { break }
      # Subset to mask
      xj <- x[mask,j]
      xi <- x[mask,i]
      # Lag the i'th series (xi) by k lags and pad with NA
      xi <- xi[1:(length(xi)-k)]
      xi <- c(rep(NA,k),xi)
      # Again, require at least two data points to 
      # overlap, otherwise break
      mask <- which(rowSums(!is.na(cbind(xj,xi)))==2)
      if(length(mask)==0) { break }
      # And add the pairwise product sum to the output
      dotProductSums[k+1] = dotProductSums[k+1] +
        t(xj[mask]) %*% xi[mask]
    }
  }
}
dotProductSums
```

In the data there will never be `NA` in the midst of a column, but each column can have different starts and stops independently. I'm sure getting these non-NA indices of each column and then lagging them is the answer, but I've talked myself into oblivion trying to figure it out. Can anybody help me with these unpleasant loops?

Many thanks.

Comment: Why not use `R`'s `C` interface? http://adv-r.had.co.nz/C-interface.html if you already have the `C` code?

Comment: It's just a small chunk of a larger program. I could yank that chunk out and make a `.C` call but it seems like overkill since this is such a small part of the work.

Comment: Aight, just checking for simpler solutions than needing to fix slow code.

Comment: Yeah. I have done that plenty in other cases where it makes sense but this seems ridiculously simple and I've gone blind trying to read it. Usually when I start a SO question I answer it myself while typing it out. Not this time!

Comment: Rather than `which(rowSums(!is.na(x[,c(j,i)]))==2`, why not use `complete.cases(.,.)`

Comment: What do the input `x` and output `dotProductSums` represent? Can you explain in broader terms what you are trying to compute? I don't understand why you are deleting incomplete pairs before lagging, instead of the other way around. I also don't understand what you mean when you say "there will never be `NA` in the midst of a column", given that you are clearly introducing `NA` in all of the columns. Can you elaborate in your question?